# How can I prevent citations with the second author as Firstname Lastname

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex with the following command:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,
      bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
```

Now when I do a \textcite I sometimes get the following output:

> Smit and John Doe, 2011

And in the bibliography

> Smit, Peter and John Doe (May 2011). “Using

I find this ugly. How can I get the citation to be:

> Smit and Doe, 2011

And the bibliography to be

> Smit, Peter and Doe, John (May 2011). “Using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible that `\textcite` will result in citations like `Smit and John Doe, 2011` (including `Doe`s first name) because biblatex since v1.4 will fully disambiguate individual author names and name lists. Just see my example.

The Month appearing in addition to the year is actually a built-in feature of biblatex. Just use the `date` field instead of `year`, and conform to the required format. (Details may be found in section 2.3.8 of the documentation.)

For the reordering of names, I prefer the form `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`. See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) ("Bibliography -- order of first names and last names") for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{S11x,
  author = {Smit, Peter and Doe, Jane},
  date = {2011},
  title = {Me and Jane},
}
@misc{S11y,
  author = {Smit, Peter and Doe, John},
  date = {2011},
  title = {Me and John},
}
@misc{S11z,
  author = {Smit, Peter and McGee, Bobby},
  date = {2011-05},
  title = {Me and Bobby McGee},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\textcite{S11x}

\textcite{S11y}

\textcite{S11z}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Name disambiguation only works with `biber` as backend. Replace `biber` with `bibtex8` in my example and see what happens. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was indeed my problem. I had a certain bib entry with Doe, J and an entry with Doe, John. Fixing that solved my problem. About the month, I don't mind that  one being there at all.

Comment: Isn't there a way to remove the "name disambiguation" feature from biber?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use multiple `bibstyle` and `citestyle` commands if you are using the same format for both.  So your command to load `biblatex` should be:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
```

(Since the `authoryear-comp` and `authoryear` `bbx` files are the same, there's no need to have separate `bibstyle` and `citestyle` specifications in this case.)

Your citations should show up as you request with the standard `authoryear-comp` format. If only *certain* items show up incorrectly, then this is likely a problem with how the `.bib` record itself is entered.  If after comparing a `.bib` file record that works with one that doesn't, you are still having problems with this, you should  edit your question showing the actual record from your `.bib` file that causes the problem.

With respect to the ordering of names, add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{last-first/first-last}{last-first}
```

With respect to having the Month appear in the date field in the bibliography, this is quite unorthodox.  Are you sure you want to do this? I'm sure it's possible, but it might require some work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually, when you add the month field to the bib file, it will be included automatically. For the citation, I tried it now with an empty tex file, and it seems the same commands give me now only last names. Are there any packages that could interfere with biblatex?

Comment: A, no packages, but lockstep's answer was spot on. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @Peter: You should still accept @Alan's advice with regard to using multiple `style` options.

Comment: I switched to BibLaTeX just today and these information are priceless – especially the last `\DeclareNameAlias`. Thank you.