# Remove name disambiguation from biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I have the problem shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16748/how-can-i-prevent-citations-with-the-second-author-as-firstname-lastname)

Using biber, sometimes I get citation like "Markus J (2016)" and sometimes "Markus JG (2015)". The two are the same author, but in the .bib file sometimes there is just one first name and sometimes there are two.

I don't have the time right now to fix the bib file. I just want to use biber and disable the "full name disambiguation" feature. How can I do that?

Using bibtex I don't have this problem, but I have a warning in the error log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable name disambiguation with biblatex's option `uniquename=false`.